# How to disable autofilter in closedXml c#?

Tags: c#, excel, closedxml

I am facing a weird problem in closedXML library.

I am exporting a datatable to .xlsx (excel file) using closedXML library.
By default, autofilter is enabled in the library.

I want to disable or remove the autofilter and export only the datatable.

Here is the code I tried but its not working

```
XLWorkbook wb = new XLWorkbook();
var ws = wb.Worksheets.Add("Test");
ws.Cell(1, 1).InsertTable(dataTable);
ws.AutoFilter.Enabled = false;
ws.Columns().AdjustToContents();
wb.SaveAs("Report.xlsx");
```

and I also tried

```
ws.AutoFilter.Clear();
```

Even the column wise clear filter is not working

```
ws.AutoFilter.Column(1).Clear();
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Try to use below code and it should work fine

```
ws.Tables.FirstOrDefault().ShowAutoFilter = false;
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! You might want to read this page before you post your next question. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Its working. And I also found how to disable autofilter all sheet.

foreach (IXLWorksheet workSheet in wb.Worksheets)
                    {
                        foreach (IXLTable table in workSheet.Tables)
                        {
                            workSheet.Table(table.Name).ShowAutoFilter = false;
                            workSheet.Columns().AdjustToContents();
                        }
                    }

Comment: Great, note that AdjustToContents might takes time based on the amount of your data

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, and the following code didn't work for me,

```
ws.Tables.FirstOrDefault().ShowAutoFilter = false;
```

I have ClosedXML version 0.93, what worked for me is:

```
ws.Tables.FirstOrDefault().SetShowAutoFilter(false);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use  ws.Worksheet(1).AutoFilter.Clear()
'Vb.net

Answer (score 0):

this might also work:

```
ws.AutoFilterMode = False
```

Answer (score 0):

to remove all tables filter you can use Linq ForEach.

```
ws.Tables.ForEach(x=>x.ShowAutoFilter = false);
```

Answer (score 0):

In ClosedXML version 0.101.0 (.net core 7), I needed to use:

```
worksheet.RangeUsed().SetAutoFilter(false);
```

to remove the auto filter.  Without this, ClosedXML was giving an error that didn't appear in previous versions:

> The range 'worksheetname'!A1:F2 overlaps with the worksheet's autofilter.